# "Private" not not really private?

Tags: php

```
class Test
{
    private $private = "";

    public function add($string) {
        $this->private[] = $string;
    }

    public function evaluate(Test $container) {
        return $container->private;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->add("zero");
$test->add("one");
$test->add("two");

$result = new Test();
print_r($result->evaluate($test));
```

The above code demonstrates the dump of a private string, how is this possible?
Then, why is it called "private"?

Can anyone explain this to me?

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => one
    [1] => two 
    [2] => four
)
```

Comment: Because you're calling it through another function in your class. It's only private to the current class and any extended classes. If you tried to call `$result->private` directly it wouldn't work.

Comment: Private to this class. You can't access it from outside.

Comment: @BenFortune I believe you're missing the question, he's accessing a private attribute from a different instance of the same class.

Comment: @smassy - He isn't though, he's accessing it from the $container variable, which is the original Test class instance injected into the second instance of Test

Comment: This is the way it works, and it's documented in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are calling that private property from inside the class. `private` means it can only be used by properties and methods inside it's own class. You call a method, which is allowed to use that property. Private properties are accessible by it's class, even if it's a different instance of the class.

You'll find the following:

```
print_r($result::$private);
```

Will give you the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access private property

Answer (score 1):

`private` in PHP means *private to any object of the same type.*

As [stated here in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and protected members even though they are not the same instances.

Yes, it is different to some other languages, but it is documented, and this is the way it works.

Comment: And it would make it a pain to implement an equals method if it was not the case

Answer (score 0):

This is because even though the `attribute $private` is private, the class Test still knows about it and can access it, even though it's a different instance. If you were to create a second class Test2() with the same `evaluate method` which expects a `Test` instance then the evaluate will fail. This is a bit tricky, but the class Test knows all about its members even from remote instances.

Answer (score 0):

`public function evaluate` is public and it can access private variable inside the class. you can't direct access the public variable like `$result->$private`

Answer (score 0):

is private because you can't access this variable/member out of class.